# Table design with joining tables or separate ID in main table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

I'm designing a database that has a couple of tables; FAQ's, Bulletins, and Attachments.  Bulletins and FAQ's could have an attachment associated with them, so my initial thought was to create a joining table with the two primary keys as a composite key:

```
Bulletin
--------
BulletinID
Subject
Description
Notes

Attachment
-----------
AttachmentID
FileName
FilePath
etc.
```

Joining table:

```
BulletinAttachments
-------------------
BulletinID
AttachmentID
```

As I design this, I also thought, what if other entities are introduced later (say Newsletter, Email, etc.) that need Attachments as well.  I would have to create a joining table for each of these entities.  Not awful, but it made me think, what if I got rid of the joining tables and put an AttachmentType in the Attachment table and then assigned the type accordingly:

```
AttachmentType
--------------
AttachmentTypeID
AttachmentType
Description
```

The data in that table would be:
1-Bulletin
2-FAQ
3-Newsletter
4-Email

Then the Attachment table would hold the AttachmentTypeID to identify it:

```
Attachments
-----------
AttachmentID
AttachmentTypeID
FileName
FilePath
etc.
```

So my question is, for performance wise (using SQL 2008 R2), is there a better choice between the two?  Is there a better way to design this?  My concern with using individual joining tables is that we may have more entities come along and to accommodate Attachments, we would have to create a joining table and on our front-end software, we would have to write logic for it whereas the AttachmentTypeID would allow the front-end to insert a new AttachmentType and no db interaction would be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second solution doesn't have a way to link the attachment to the item, just what kind of item it is.

Even if it did (ie: an itemID), what you would create would be a violation of 4th Normal form - ie: a multivalued dependency.

Stick with your first plan, but consider whether Bulletins are fundamentally different to Newsletters, Emails, FAQs, etc in your application. If you do need a new table for Newsletters, add a new table for NewsletterAttachments.

Also consider, are you going to share attachments between different items, or types of item?

Comment: Thanks Posiluska, I didn't even see that with the 2nd choice, they aren't linked in any way (knew something wasn't right, which is why I posted my thoughts in the first place).  Also, you are correct; Attachments could be shared between different items.

Answer (score 0):

I am totally agree with podiluska. you need to create separate table for each type of attachment otherwise you cant map itemid with attachment and you will face a problem of joining table for different type of attachment . also if you make separate table for each type of attachment then performance will be faster .